Google Form After Submission - 'Something Went Wrong'
We have a membership application form that we have been using for a few years without issue - with over a 100 submissions. However a member today has encountered 'Something Went Wrong' after completing the forming and pressing submit. I have the same issue. No notifications in the form. The spreadsheet is still connected.
Cleared the cache on Chrome browser.
Tried on Microsoft Edge.
Two different devices.
Two different people have tried to subit the form.

You might try the Google Docs Help Community https://support.google.com/docs/community?hl=en&sjid=12978193634797740964-NC

Or a general search on "google forms something went wrong", there are lots of hits
